# Add dynamically methods of an object in my context

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, instead of :

```
dummy = require('dummy')

dummy.aMethod()
dummy.anotherMethod()
```

I want to use directly the methods in my context :

```
dummy = require('dummy')
loadMethods(dummy)

aMethod()
anotherMethod()
```

How can I implement the function loadMethods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), like this:

```
with (dummy) {
  aMethod();
  anotherMethod();
}
```

That's not recommended though, as it makes a lot of things ambiguous and not behaving as you would expect them to.

To do exactly what you're asking for, you can add these methods to the `global` object. You can use something like this:

```
for (var prop in dummy) {
  if (dummy.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    global[prop] = dummy[prop];
  }
}
```

This approach has its limitations too, though - for example, you can't use aMethod() in the body of a function, the `this` object will be wrong (of course, you could use `bind` to keep it correct). Also, `global` is not really global, but module-scoped - so every module gets its own `global` object.

So, weighing the options, you should probably stick with using the methods through `dummy`. This way you'll always get the expected behavior (`this` will be `dummy`) and you'll have a clear indication that the methods you're using are actually implemented in the `dummy` module and use its state. Find a good IDE and typing shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the malleability of `this`. When a function is called without being bound to a specific scope for `this` (which can be done through [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), or in a method-context) then `this` refers to the global object. This code will work in browsers as well as Node.js, but will of course overwrite any other globally-scoped function with the same name. Use with caution...in general I'd recommend against using it.

```
function loadMethods(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof(obj[prop]) === 'function') {
            this[prop] = obj[prop]
        }
    }
}
```

You can learn more about `this` context [here](http://helephant.com/2009/11/29/javascript-method-context/)